# I seem to have broken validates_confirmation_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seem to have broken `validates_confirmation_of` in my rails app.

My model looks like this:

```
class Blark
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :text
  validates_confirmation_of :text
end
```

This is what happens when I use it:

```
0 HAL work/nrb-brewery-management % rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.5)

1.9.3p0 :001 > b = Blark.new
 => #<Blark:0xae2e2d0> 

1.9.3p0 :002 > b.text = 'llama'
 => "llama" 

1.9.3p0 :003 > b.text_confirmation
 => nil 

1.9.3p0 :004 > b.valid?
 => true
```

Why is `b` valid here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Rails documentation](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000081) states:

"NOTE: This check is performed only if password_confirmation is not nil, and by default only on save. To require confirmation, make sure to add a presence check for the confirmation attribute:"

So add a presence check to your class, e.g.

```
class Blark
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :text
  validates_confirmation_of :text
  validates_presence_of :text, :text_confirmation
end
```